# Can't install/upgrade packages with CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan

I tried to install some modules with CPAN, but it's giving the following error for every module.

```
CPAN installation problem " Package contains both files[bignum-0.30.tar] and directories[bignum-0.30]; not recognized as a perl package, giving up, won't make".
Untarred RRD-Simple-1.44.tar successfully
Package contains both files[RRD-Simple-1.44.tar] and directories[RRD-Simple-1.44]; not recognized as a perl package, giving up
  Package contains both files[RRD-Simple-1.44.tar] and directories[RRD-Simple-1.44]; not recognized as a perl package, giving up, won't make
Running Untarred RRD-Simple-1.44.tar successfully
Package contains both files[RRD-Simple-1.44.tar] and directories[RRD-Simple-1.44]; not recognized as a perl package, giving up
  Package contains both files[RRD-Simple-1.44.tar] and directories[RRD-Simple-1.44]; not recognized as a perl package, giving up, won't make
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test.
```

Although it was working a few days back. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What did you do? (command you are trying to execute)?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. 
Deleting `~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm` and reconfiguring cpan (`#cpan> o conf init` ) helped